# What does it mean "Authentication Type" in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

authenticate what ?
For visiting or managing the project or sth else ?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357210/google-app-engine-authentication?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The authentication type is what users can use to login to your webapp with their google accounts or other providers. The federated login can give you problems such as broken access to datastore admin, so recommended is using the google accounts or [this project engine-auth](http://code.scotchmedia.com/engineauth/docs/index.html) I recommend if you want something more advanced.